# python program which having separate plugins ,How I can run it on the machine whose having only default python not plugins?

Tags: python

Let I developed a program in pycharm not only using  the default python library,but also import different different  plugins to pycharm. But I want to run this program in another  machine which doesn't have any other separate plugins except default python. How can I run this program on that machine?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `requirements.txt` file in which you can note down your dependencies either manually or through using `pip freeze > requirements.txt` over the command line. The easiest way to accomplish this is probably by using [PyCharm's embedded Terminal](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/working-with-embedded-local-terminal.html). After putting your requirements in a `requirements.txt`, you can use `pip install -r requirements.txt` to install the requirements you specified. Here is some further information from the pip documentation: https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/1.1/requirements.html

It's recommended to use a virtual environment. The standard library has a built-in module for this, about which you can read here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Comment: By all means use a virtualenv to install the program and it's requirements - unless you don't care breaking some other program that depends on different versions of the same packages... Also beware that outside a virtualenv, `pip freeze` will list ALL available packages from your installation, whether your app needs them or not, so better to write your requirements file manually (grepping for `import` in your project tree should be a good starting point).

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention that. I edited my reply to include a link to the documentation.